# angular-ui tabs loading template in tab-content

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui

I'm using the tabs in angular-ui using this controller:

```
$scope.panes = [
    { title:"Home",      content:"home" , active: true},
    { title:"Settings",  content:"settings"},
    { title:"View",      content:"view"}
];
```

and this in the html file:

```
<tabs>
    <pane
      active="pane.active"
      heading="{{pane.title}}"
      ng-repeat="pane in panes"
    >
      {{pane.content}}
    </pane>
  </tabs>
```

but i want to set the content as a template how can I do that, I tried setting the ng-include code in this [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/VUUPhgN602vHyMm1hEcT?p=preview), but didn't work.
Thanks in advance.

## update:

if you find this solution and you'r not using angular-bootstrap v0.12 you need to update the code to [the new syntax of v0.13](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/tabs) like this:

```
<tabset>
    <tab
      active="pane.active"
      heading="{{pane.title}}"
      ng-repeat="pane in panes"
    >
      <div ng-include="pane.content"></div>
    </tab>
  </tabset>
```

I already updated the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/VUUPhgN602vHyMm1hEcT?p=preview) to have the syntax of the angular-bootstrap v0.13.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Just add the **ng-include** as a child of the pane

```
<tabs>
    <pane active="pane.active"
          heading="{{pane.title}}"
          ng-repeat="pane in panes">
        <div ng-include="pane.content"></div>
    </pane>
</tabs>
```

The reason this works is that the scope variable pane is not yet available when you use the **ng-include** in the same element as the **ng-repeat** that creates the pane variable.

This is because the priority value of the **ng-include** is 0(the default) while the priority of the ng-repeat is 1000 and so the order of execution is:

1. ng-include
2. ng-repeat

See the [directive docs](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive)

Comment: Thanks that worked, but could you explain why it worked this way not how i wrote it the first time, or just point me to where I can found it.