# How to load data for a div\tab on clicking the tab

Tags: html, angularjs, jquery-ui, tabs

We currently have a Silverlight application that has the following functionality.

1. Page load with multiple tab pages. The tab pages may or may not contain more tab pages.
2. None of the tab pages data has been retrieved. Except for the one visible and in front.
3. On the user clicking the tab page to bring it to the front - the app then retrieves the data for that tab page.

We are now creating an HTML5 and Javascript version of this application and are after the same functionality.

I am new to this and am using the jquery-ui tab control which is done by using a div.

Comment: I suggest you look into [$routeprovider](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider) as I think it might be used to implement your needed functionality

Comment: @JaredReeves I had a quick look at the $routeProvider and some sample usages and it doesn't seem to be what we are after - however I will implement something utilising it and see. Thanks. This is the link I went to http://viralpatel.net/blogs/angularjs-routing-and-views-tutorial-with-example/

Comment: Possible solution in another stackoverflow question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19781004/tabs-with-angular-loading-tab-content-on-click-only-with-http