# Add multiple ui-grids using ng-include

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have multiple tabs on a page for different statuses. Each tab is having its own `ui-grid` and it is included by `ng-include`. The sample code is given below.

```
 <tab heading="@L("Incomplete")">
        <div ng-include="'~/App/common/views/incentives/incomplete.cshtml'"></div>
    </tab>

    <tab heading="@L("PendingApproval")">
        <div ng-include="'~/App/common/views/incentives/pendingApproval.cshtml'"></div>
    </tab>

    <tab heading="@L("AwaitingTracker")">
        <div ng-include="'~/App/common/views/incentives/awaitingtracker.cshtml'"></div>
    </tab>

    <tab heading="@L("DistributedToSales")">
        <div ng-include="'~/App/common/views/incentives/distributed2sales.cshtml'"></div>
    </tab>
```

I would like to achieve the below functionality.

- Each tab will load the data when we will focus on it.
- As now it all the tabs are loading data at a same time but all `ui-grid`s are not loading the data. Only first grid loads the data. refer this video http://screencast.com/t/HM0cfjOgCK

Answer (score 0):

You can try to reload tabs content  on select:

```
<tab heading="@L("AwaitingTracker")" select="reload()">
        <div ng-include="'~/App/common/views/incentives/awaitingtracker.cshtml'"></div>
    </tab>

<script>

function reload(){
 if($scope.tabs[tabIndex].isLoaded){
      return
    }
    /* or make request for data , delayed to show Loading... vs cache */
    $timeout(function(){
        var jsonFile='data'+(tabIndex +1)+'.json'
        $http.get(jsonFile).then(function(res){
            $scope.tabs[tabIndex].content=res.data;
            $scope.tabs[tabIndex].isLoaded=true;
        });

    }, 2000)
}

</script>
```

i havent check that this reload() method is working, but i have same problem with slider in tab. With refreshing slider using timeout it shows init values correclty. Check this reload for tabs: [tabs with angular: loading tab content on click only with $http](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19781004/tabs-with-angular-loading-tab-content-on-click-only-with-http)